# this.props.enableEdit is not a function error while executing function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to edit the entered text by edit button. Edit button invokes triggerEdit function that reads enableEdit property. My code goes like this:

```js
    class App extends React.Component {

  

       constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
    todo:[]
  };
};

entertodo(keypress){
  var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
  if( keypress.charCode == 13 )

  {
    this.setState({
      todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, checked:false}),
      editing:false
    });
    this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
  };
};
todo(todo,i){
  return (
    <li className={todo.checked===true? 'line':'newtodo'}>
      <div >
        <input type="checkbox" className="option-input checkbox" checked={todo.checked} />
        <div key={todo.id} className="item">
          {todo.Value}
          <span className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}>X</span>
          <button onClick={this.triggerEdit.bind(this,i)}type='button'>edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

remove(i){
  this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
  this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
};
todoCompleted(i){
   var todo=this.state.todo;
   todo[i].checked =todo[i].checked? false:true;
     this.setState({
       todo:this.state.todo
     });

 };
allCompleted=()=>{
  var todo = this.state.todo;
  var _this = this
  todo.forEach(function(item) {
    item.className = _this.state.finished ? "newtodo" : "line"
    item.checked = !_this.state.finished
  })
  this.setState({todo: todo, finished: !this.state.finished})
};

enableEdit(i){
  var todo= this.state.todo;
  var edittodo=todo[i];
};
triggerEdit(i) {
   this.props.enableEdit(i)
  };
  render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
        <div className="lines"></div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
          <span onClick={this.allCompleted}id="all">^</span>
        </div>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <ul className="decor">
            {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
    .line {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
.newtodo{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I tried some ways but the error i got is **this.props.enableEdit is not a function**

Answer (score 1):

With how your code is written it should just be: `this.enableEdit(i)`
enableEdit is a method on the component, not a prop you are passing into it

Comment: are you not getting the console error anymore at least?

Comment: yeah m not getting console error, but m not sure what to write in code so that i can edit the entered text

Comment: http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/VKPXoN here is a working pen, the changes i made was add a text input if the todo is in an editing state, and then a new funciton for editTodo. Really the main issue here is you are making one component do to many things, the react way is you should have multiple components instead of one mammoth component trying to do so many things.

Comment: With how i made it it automatically saves, you'd have to add some of your own functionality for the editing box to close, or you could add in a save button. The text input relies on the todo item to be in an editing state, so just need to change editing to false and it would go away. How you implement it would be up to you